# How does Google Chrome Syn Computers with different users loged in

Tags: google-chrome, email, sync

At workplace my colleague and I recently found out that she can view my history on her computer, while I can view her history on my computer. The E-mails we signed in in our Chromes are our personal and are not the same, but somehow the histories are shared and syncronized. How is it possible and how can we fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive off the top of my head why this would have occurred in the first place, but there is a fix. In your Google Chrome, go to the following:

```
Menu > Settings > Advanced Sync Settings..
```

From there you can set manual control over what is being synced, so you can disable the History. I don't believe this is a retroactive change, so you will still have to clear your history to clear any old entries that have already synced to you.